# Health Checks failing in target group for k8s application load balancer

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-ecr

I have an EKS cluster with an application load balancer with a target group setup for each application environment. In my cluster I am building my application from a base docker image that is stored in a private ECR repository. I have confirmed that my pods are able to pull from the private ECR repo due to a secret I have setup to allow the private ECR image to be pulled. I am having a problem with the base docker image being able to get into a healthy state in the target group. I updated to containerPort in my deployment to match the port of the target group. I am not sure if that is how it needs to be configured. Below is how I defined everything for this namespace. I also have my dockerfile for the base image. Any advice how I can get a base docker image into a healthy state for me to build my application would be helpful.

**dev.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
        name: dev
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
        namespace: dev
        name: dev-deployment
spec:
        selector:
                matchLabels:
                        app.kubernetes.io/name: dev-app
        replicas: 2
        template:
                metadata:
                        labels:
                                app.kubernetes.io/name: dev-app
                spec:
                        containers:
                          - name: dev-app
                            image: xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/private/base-docker-image:latest
                            imagePullPolicy: Always
                            ports:
                                    - containerPort: 30411
                        imagePullSecrets:
                        - name: dev
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
        namespace: dev
        name: dev-service
spec:
        ports:
                - port: 80
                  targetPort: 80
                  protocol: TCP
        type: NodePort
        selector:
                app.kubernetes.io/name: dev-app
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
        namespace: dev
        name: dev-ingress
        annotations:
                kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
                alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
                alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
spec:
        rules:
                - http:
                        paths:
                                - path: /*
                                  backend:
                                          serviceName: dev-service
                                          servicePort: 80
---
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM private/base-docker-image:latest

COPY . /apps
WORKDIR /apps
RUN npm run build

ENV ML_HOST=$HOST ML_PORT=$PORT ML_USER=$USER ML_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD

CMD ["npm", "run", "dockerstart"]
```

**Registered Targets**
[image]

**Health Check Settings**
[image]

Comment: Your service targetPort should to be set to the port opened by application that is 30411 as suggested by deployment yaml. Does it solve it?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility.

As confirmed in the comments the solution is to set the `targetPort` to the port opened by the application which is `30411` as mentioned in the deployment's yaml configuration.